# Borrowed value does not live long enough requiring static lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm getting this error with a sample code at this [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54dbdbd06309bdc3ea52e956ea0fe6dc)

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `text` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:34:38
   |
34 |     let item = NotLongEnough { text: &text };
   |                                      ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
35 |     let mut wrapper = Container { buf: Vec::new() };
36 |     wrapper.add(Box::new(item));
   |                 -------------- cast requires that `text` is borrowed for `'static`
...
40 | }
   | - `text` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

The contents are:

```
trait TestTrait {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &str;
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct NotLongEnough<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> TestTrait for NotLongEnough<'a> {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &str {
        self.text
    }
}

struct Container {
    buf: Vec<Box<dyn TestTrait>>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn TestTrait>) {
        self.buf.push(item);
    }

    pub fn output(&self) {
        for item in &self.buf {
            println!("{}", item.get_text());
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let text = "test".to_owned();
    let item = NotLongEnough { text: &text };
    let mut wrapper = Container { buf: Vec::new() };
    wrapper.add(Box::new(item));
    wrapper.output();

    Ok(())
}
```

I have no clue why `cast requires that text is borrowed for 'static`
Could someone please help me with this? I've no idea what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TLDR: Fixed version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f01ad6df3f54e35cd2b9d7da4129df9)

The problem is in your `Container` definition:

```
struct Container {
    buf: Vec<Box<dyn TestTrait>>,
}
```

The statement `dyn TestTrait` is equivalent to `dyn TestTrait + 'static`, meaning that your trait objects must not contain any references with lifetime less than `'static`.

In order to fix the problem, you have to replace that trait bound with a less strict one:

```
struct Container<'a> {
    buf: Vec<Box<dyn TestTrait + 'a>>,
}
```

Now instead of `'static`, the container requires `'a`. And  you have to apply that change to the implementation as well:

```
   pub fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn TestTrait + 'a>) { // notice the new trait-bound
        self.buf.push(item);
   }
```

Relevant resources:

- [Trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_bounds.html)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @SanhuLi please "accept" the answer if it helped you

Comment: ~~Do you know how I can do that? I didn't see any button anywhere to accept it. I saw an up arrow and has clicked on it yesterday~~ Ah, I see, the checkmark is the accept button